# iPhone and asp.NET MVC File Upload with URL Parameter

Tags: iphone, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

this is going to be a question about sending data from the iPhone to a MVC 3 function.

To get into the topic what I'm already doing and what is working, just to see the style how I'm implementing the connections.

Here I have a sample MVC Controller function, running on my IIS 7.0.

The **SampleController** : Controller

```
public ActionResult MyFunction(MyObject object) {
    ContentResult result = new ContentResult();
    result.Content = some content from the server encoded as JSON
    return result;
}
```

On the iPhone I call this function like this.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%d/%@/%@", _host, _port, Sample, MyFunction];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setHTTPBody:json]; // some json encoded object that fits the MyObject from asp.NET

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
// synchronous so the sample code is shorter
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];

// Do some error handling and http status code stuff and finally the json stuff from the NSData object
```

So this stuff is all working fine, but now I'm at a point where it get's confusing. I need to upload a NSData Object, containing image Data or other stuff. Uploading just the file using mulipart/form-data as shown [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4385051/633945). But when adding some url parameters it does not work anymore.

**________________________________________________________________________________________**

So now there are two options from here to solve my problem:

The first approach is: **How would a NSURLRequest look like for using a Function like this? Or is this even possible?**

```
public ActionResult MyFunction(MyObject object, byte[] binaryData) {
    // Some server stuff ect.
}
```

**Or how would I build my NSURLRequest using my first Function and adding a file attachment?**

**Edit**

Here is how I build my current file upload request. It is basically the same I do in the second code snippet.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%d/%@/%@", _host, _port, Sample, MyFunction];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setHTTPBody:json];
```

And finally the file attachment. **Note** When only using the file attachment without parameters everything works fine, but well yeah the params are missing.

```
+ (void)attachFile:(NSData *)fileData withFilename:(NSString *)filename toRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request {
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------94712889831966399282116247425";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename]
                  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:fileData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSData *oldBody = [request HTTPBody];
if (oldBody) {
    [body appendData:oldBody];
}

[request setHTTPBody:body];
}
```

So my guess is now, that there is some boundary stuff for the parameters missing.

**Note**

As an addition I use a synchronous NSURLConnection on a background Thread.

```
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];
```

Comment: Posting the relevant code would help to answer your question ;) The most errors occur when encoding the URL string containing params, or when creating the rather error prone multipart/form-data body.

Comment: You might now check if the server understands the parameters in the URL. Ask the web-service developers, too. If not (likely), wrap each parameter into a part, separated by the correct boundaries. Ideally, each part's value "should" have a Content-Type and Content-Length. This of course will become cumbersome, where you might start thinking of a third party, tool -- or even better: use JSON as transport format.

Comment: "As an addition I use a synchronous NSURLConnection on a background Thread." As a serious developer creating serious apps, don't use convenient APIs which are for sample and toy apps only. That is, use `NSURLConnection` in asynchronous mode, implementing the delegates. You need that anyway, later when you have to implement your server trust authentication with a self signed cert.

Comment: Well no need for that right now, it's for a research project in school about the basic principles of convergent encryption. But thank you for pointing out that the authentication challenge does not work with synchronous connections using NSURLConnection! I guess for production I would use it async with delegate or AFNetworking. +1

Comment: Server trust authentication will (very likely) work with the convenient API when the root certificate is signed by a Certificate Authority. Self signed certificates will require you to override a delegate message, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given sample (please add more actual code), it is difficult to tell where there is an issue - but there are a few potential culprits.

First off, the request depends on what your server will accept.

A POST request usually embeds "parameters" in the multipart/form-data body. Browsers would not include "parameters"  in the URL - and a server may not expect or accept this as well.

Comment: That's a really helpful question. I didn't know that in multipart-form-data the params are encapsulated in the body. That could actually be the reason. I'll add a detailed Code.